# print IPOPT parameters

Tags: optimization, julia, ipopt

I would like to get some parameters from IPOPT, like for instance,

```
Using Ipopt 
k = barrier_tol_factor
```

I know this doesn't work. Does anyone now how I can access thoes?

I tried with

```
Ipopt.barrier_tol_factor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems getting the current option value is tricky. But you can set this option and then the value should be known:

```
Ipopt.AddIpoptNumOption(solver, "barrier_tol_factor", 15.0)
```

BTW the default value is **10.0**.